# Remove whitespace before or after a character with regex

Tags: c#, regex, replace, expression

I new in regex and i want to find a good solution for replacing whitespace before or after the `/` char in my sub string.

I have got string like

```
"Path01 /Some folder/ folder (2)"
```

i checked regex

```
@"\s?()\s?"
```

but this incorrect for me. I must get in output

```
Path01/Some folder/folder (2)
```

Can you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, @MichaelGeary, String.Trim will remove whitespace at the beginning or end of all my string. But i need remove after my specification symbol "/"

Comment: I edited your question so, specifying your `/` symbol needs. Otherwise people searching for `Trim()` function will not sent in the right way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

```
@"\s*/\s*"
```

and replace with `/`.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cs*%2F%5Cs*&i=Path01%20%2FSome%20folder%2F%20folder%20%282%29&r=%2F)

The pattern matches zero or more (`*`) whitespace chars (`\s`), then a `/` and then again 0+ whitespace chars.

C#:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(s, @"\s*/\s*", "/");
```

Comment: Your answer is right!
Thank you very much! Have a nice day! Good luck!